# Keep session when using requests_html's render function

Tags: python, pyppeteer

I have a small internal webpage that requires a log in. When logged in, a simple HTML page is loaded, and there are javascript scripts that load the actual content of the pages.

I want to:

- Log into the page
- Run the javascript
- Extract information from the page
- Find links in the page and repeat the procedure

I found that there is a package called requests_html that sounds like the goal is to be able to do something like this. I managed to use requests_html to log into the page and get the HTML view of the page I want. It should then be possible to call

```
response.html.render()
```

and requests_html should then use pyppeteer, that downloads and launches a headless chromium, loads the webpage, renders the page, and then returns back the result. This actually works, but it only returns the log in page. The session information from requests_html is not passed to pyppeteer and/or chromium.

**Is it possible to use the same session, or do I need to try to log in using only pyppeteer?**

Here is a code example, but you need a small webpage with form login and javascript rendering to try it on:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from lxml import html

url = "https://example.com"
username = "user@example.com"
password = "hunter2"
session = HTMLSession()
payload = {
    "input_user": username,
    "input_password": password
}
response = session.post(url, data=payload)
# Logged in here
response = session.get(url)
response.html.render()

# Output from this shows login page
print(response.html.html)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install the github version of requests-html and use the following parameter to render():

```
response.html.render(send_cookies_session=True)
```

This will maintain your login authorization from your session in the Chromium page instance used to render.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you post a link to the github version that you are talking about as well?

Answer (score 1):

The download of the github version (I suppose a less stable version) is not required. You can specify reload=False as follows:

```
response.html.render(reload=False)
```

Just saw that this is from 2019... I guess better late than never and yes that is what she said ;-)